# Manipulating dataframe columns so top 25% rows contain a value, R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I have a dataframe (called "df") in R and I have made a new column (called "col") which is currently filled with NA's. There is another column in df which is called risk and I have ordered the dataframe so those rows with highest risk are at the top.

I want the top 25% of columns (so with top 25% risk) to contain the word "x" in them and the other 75% to have "y" in them. I'm thinking I need a for loop to do this but could someone please me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(df$risk > quantile(df$risk, 0.75), "x", "y")
```

If you want to save this into your data.frame use

```
df$col = ifelse(df$risk > quantile(df$risk, 0.75), "x", "y")
```

Comment: Thankyou for this! I used this, but this just prints the values in my console, how do I get it to update the column in my dataframe?